# Why I'm unable to add bootstrap in Angular JS?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I've installed a Angular UI Bootstrap 2.5.0 package in my visual studio and I'm trying to perform a carousel operation, but it doesn't work at all. Following is my code.

```
<div class="panel-body" id="tblSubs" ng-controller="ControllerName">
    <carousel interval="myInterval">
        <slide ng-repeat="id in code">
             <h3 class="text-center">{{id.Name}}</h3>
             <p>{{id.Contact}}</p>
             <p>{{id.Info}}</p>
        </slide>
    </carousel>
</div>
```

I'm able to get the data but the data doesn't come in carousel.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 0.14.0 you need to add the `uib` prefix to some of the directives, enter `uib-carousel` instead of `carousel` etc..

```
<div uib-carousel active="active" interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
  <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id">
    <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h4>Slide {{slide.id}}</h4>
      <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **<div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id">** What does this ng-repeat do, what does track by do?

Comment: it's just some of the code from the [carousal section](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#carousel), there's a link to a demo plunker you can check out

Comment: Okay! Thakn you this really helps!